# Apache Cordova The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

I am developing Apache Cordova app on vs 2015 community with Angularjs on onsen.

And keep getting "The system cannot find the file specified" error no matter what i've done.

Things that i've done so far:

1. Clear cordova cache, Clean, Rebuild (like a hundred times)
2. Format pc, install everything
3. Copied the solution to another pc and worked fine nothing is wrong but does not work on my pc.
4. Close vs instances and change the folder name under Appdata/roaming/microsoft/local/phonetools/Corecon

And nothing changed still getting the same error when deploy starts.

My NPM version is 3.10.10, Cordova CLI is 6.1.1, nodejs version is 6.9.4 and JDK version is 1.8.3

Comment: Can you be more detailed on your error: what application shows it, and can you copy paste the entire error log? More details on the Linux distro are also welcomed.

Comment: I was getting error from Visual Studio 2015, but after 3 days i changed nothing but works perfectly fine nothing is wrong right now. I wonder what changed. Thx

Comment: I'm having the same issue :(